# Questions about Caratheodory's Theorem on convex sets

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand [Caratheodory's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) on Wikipedia. There are two points that I just do not understand:

1. Why do we suppose $k > d+1$ instead of $k > d$?
2. Why can we set $\mu_1 = -\sum_{j=2}^k \mu_i$ ? I mean even if the vectors $(x_j-x_1)$ are linearly dependent, why can we choose the $\mu$ ?

Could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First question

The answer to your first question lies on the statement of the theorem. Given the convex combination $x = \sum_{j = 1}^{k} \lambda_jx_j$, if $k \leq d + 1$, then it satisfies the statement of the theorem, so we directly omit this case and suppose the opposite $k > d + 1$.

But I think that this is not what you actually wanted to ask, and what lies further ahead might answer to your real question, as it provides some insights on why we need $d+1$ points instead of $d$.

#### Second question

If $k > d + 1$, then the $k - 1$ vectors described in the proof must be linearly dependent, as the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $d$ (having $k > d + 1$ is equivalent to having $k - 1 > d$).

Notice here that the condition $k > d + 1$ is key, as if it were $k > d$, then we wouldn't be able to guarantee that the vectors are linearly dependent, as $k$ could be $d + 1$, as it satisfies $k > d$, and then we would have a family of $d$ vectors, which could be linearly independent.

A vector space of dimension $d$ has the property that any linearly independent family has at most $d$ vectors. Remind that a family of $n$ vectors is linearly independent if $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_k x_k = 0 \iff \forall k, 1\leq k\leq n, \lambda_k = 0$$

As our family is not linearly independent, this means that there is some combination that is equal to $0$, where not every $\lambda_k$ is $0$, otherwise the family is linearly independent.

For the last point, notice that $$\sum_{j=2}^{k} \mu_j(x_j-x_1) = 0\iff \sum_{j=2}^{k}(\mu_jx_j - \mu_jx_1) = 0$$

Now, separating the two sums, we have: $$\left(\sum_{j=2}^{k}\mu_jx_j\right) + \left(-\sum_{j=2}^{k}\mu_jx_1\right) = 0 \iff \left(\sum_{j=2}^{k}\mu_jx_j\right) + \mu_1x_1 = 0 \iff \sum_{j=1}^{k}\mu_jx_j = 0$$

Where $\mu_1$ as defined in the proof.

Comment: I am pretty sure this proof should be pretty straightforward for students already familiar with concepts of vector spaces, so I suspect that you lack some knowledge regarding the subject, for this reason, don't hesitate to highlight the parts that you don't understand so that I can clarify them for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. now I understand it.